# Srcset and picture in firefox 38

Tags: firefox

The "caniuse" website claims firefox 38 supports `srcset` and the `picture` attribute, but changing the viewport from width 1600 px to 250 px on http://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/ seems to have no effect. The property `dom.image.srcset.enabled` is set to true. Is this a bug or is it not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Firefox bug that will be solved in Firefox 41.

See on Bugzilla: [Bug 1135812 - picture element does not react to resize/viewport changes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1135812)